# Nginx with php5-fpm Magento Optimization

Tags: php, magento, optimization, nginx, server

I have an Nginx setup with php5-fpm with the following server:

Amazon EC2 instance
t2.medium
cpu: 2 vcore
memory: 4 GB
Storage: EBS Only

The Max user concurrently online is stable around 250 users once it gets to 300 users it starts showing error request. This test is over 30 seconds.

The home page that I use in the test is about 5MB.

Just wondering if I could optimize more to allow more users. Note - the data base is host on another server. so don't take database into account.

I always thought Nginx server is suppose to solve the 10K problem. well even in this case it is not static page, It would expect the user to be more than 300 users.

Maybe php-fpm is the bottle neck

Ulimit Setting

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31534
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31534
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Nginx conf

```
events {
        worker_connections 2048;
        multi_accept on;
}
```

php5-fpm conf

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]

pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid







;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

php pool conf

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

  listen = 127.0.0.1:7161

pm = dynamic
request_terminate_timeout = 600
chdir = /
```

Comment: Can you remove all the commented out lines from your configurations so it's easier to see what you're actually doing?